# Base 64 or Image file to upload for mobile apps IOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, base64

What is the latest sayings and professionals recommendations to use images for mobile apps. I'm very confused. Being a newbie in IOS development... there are always many directions before decision. Can somebody please recommend what kind of files type should I Use. Base64 encoding to directly store into DB or Images and upload them onto the server. if base64? what datatype do you guys recommend? i'm using BLOB is that fine?
[This link says we should use base64](https://codeburst.io/the-different-ways-to-upload-images-on-mobile-android-ios-and-more-b258fc33e281#16f2)

But many says. file size is very heigh in base64 than images (JPG or PNG)s.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server, many of them have a "file" option with a callback containing the URL, then you just store the file and consume the URL. I really think that base64 is too much unnecessary processing.

The easiest one is Firebase Storage, where you can just put the file as image/jpeg and receive an URL to that image. Another option is Cloudinary, there are many options.

Most apps just download images from URL's and show them as demanded. You can store images anywhere you want, and in your DB you store URLs from them.

Comment: You mean... i don't need to encode into base64 and only jpg/png can be pushed to db? that would be amazing!

Comment: absolutely, there is no need to encode, they accept many contentTypes,  check their documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files